# Drools is throwing exception in Maven project

Tags: java, maven, drools, xstream

I created a drools project using the version 6.5.0.Final and is running fine. But when i created a maven project its throwing error

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(Ljava/net/URL;)Ljava/lang/Object;
at org.drools.compiler.kproject.models.KieModuleModelImpl$kModuleMarshaller.fromXML(KieModuleModelImpl.java:207)
at org.drools.compiler.kproject.models.KieModuleModelImpl.fromXML(KieModuleModelImpl.java:154)
at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.ClasspathKieProject.fetchKModule(ClasspathKieProject.java:179)
at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.ClasspathKieProject.fetchKModule(ClasspathKieProject.java:141)
at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.ClasspathKieProject.discoverKieModules(ClasspathKieProject.java:112)
at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.ClasspathKieProject.init(ClasspathKieProject.java:84)
at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieContainerImpl.<init>(KieContainerImpl.java:139)
at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieServicesImpl.newKieClasspathContainer(KieServicesImpl.java:135)
at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieServicesImpl.getKieClasspathContainer(KieServicesImpl.java:101)
at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieServicesImpl.getKieClasspathContainer(KieServicesImpl.java:79)
at com.powerschool.cc.validationengine.engine.ValidationEngine.getKieSession(ValidationEngine.java:49)
at com.powerschool.cc.validationengine.engine.ValidationEngine.validationEngine(ValidationEngine.java:24)
```

Here is my dependencies in POM file

```
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20140107</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
        <artifactId>kie-api</artifactId>
        <version>${runtime.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
        <artifactId>drools-core</artifactId>
        <version>${runtime.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
        <artifactId>drools-compiler</artifactId>
        <version>${runtime.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
        <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
        <version>${cdi.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.weld.se</groupId>
        <artifactId>weld-se-core</artifactId>
        <version>${weld.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
         <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
         <artifactId>xstream</artifactId> 
        <version>1.4.10-java7</version> </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

This is the code

```
private KieSession getKieSession(){
    KieServices services = null;
    KieContainer container = null;
    KieSession kieSession = null;
    try{

        services = KieServices.Factory.get();
        container = services.getKieClasspathContainer();
        kieSession = container.newKieSession("ksession-rules");
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return kieSession;
}
```

getKieClasspathContainer is throwing the error.

Googled the error and found that adding Xstream dependency will solve the issue but its not. Uing Java 7 and tomcat 7. Do i need to add any other dependency to the POM?
 Anybody is having any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The version in the dependency in your POM for xstream is 1.4.10-java7.

Drools 6.5.0-Final comes with the jar file xstream-1.4.9.jar and that means that the Drools jars have been compiled against this version.

I cannot guarantee that this is the reason why you get this error but it is worth a try.

Comment: actually i tried with 1.4.9 also but it gives the same error and the exception is throwing from `services.getKieClasspathContainer();` this line

Comment: When am trying to run it using Main(), its working but when i try to run it in Tomcat I am  facing issue.